# How to use qt dbus bindings in posix thread?

Tags: c++, qt4, pthreads, qtdbus

I am writing a library for the application, which loads my library dinamycaly, and starts the execution in a posix thread. I asked the developers of the application to use QThreads, but they said that they can't change anything.

In my library, I would like to use Qt Dbus bindings, but it doesn't really work well, since it is not running in QThread context. I noticed two things :

1. I do not get responses to asynchronous calls (as explained in the [documentation for QDBusPendingCallWatcher](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdbuspendingcallwatcher.html)). Synchronous (blocking) calls are working fine.
2. I get next message when creating dbus interface :

   > QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread
   >   QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread

All information I found said that I need to create QThread to make it work, and not use posix threads, but I have no choice.

Is it possible to make QSocketNotifier work from non-QThread context? If yes, how?

---

PS I can compile qt library from sources, and can do whatever I like to it. So, even patching it would be ok.

---

I found [this patch](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/8628/) for qt 4.8 to enable installation of a custom event dispatcher. But I am not sure if it would break anything, and if it is thread safe. Will play a bit with it and see if it works.